# Problemas com session_start() no navegador Safari

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet

Estou utilizando o navegador Safari, e estou programando em PHP 5.5. inexplicavelmente o safari não segura sessão... na verdade nem cria!

Em outros navegadores o meu sistema funciona corretamente, somente no Safari tem esse problema... gostaria de saber se é alguma configuração no meu navegador, ou se é alguma coisa que tenho que configurar no PHP 5.5 ou se é alguma outra coisa que está me passando despercebido

Basicamente a única coisa que uso é:

`session_start();`

No inicio de cada arquivo que utiliza a sessão de PHP

No corpo da página index.html utilizo frames pra montar minha página, algo do tipo:

```
    <frameset>
    <frame src="topo.html"/>
    <frameset id="fraCorpo" ">
        <frame src="menu.html"  />
        <frame src="corpo.html"  />
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Tem certeza que não está bloqueado de alguma forma a criação de `cookies`. Porque as sessões normalmente são apoiadas sobre o uso de `cookie`. Dê uma olhada se alguma extensão, plugin ou configuração não está bloqueando.

Comment: O navegador Safari tá limpo de extensões, eu instalei ele a umas duas semanas, e somente pra testes aqui na empresa.......

Comment: Olá considere verificar os cookies, http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiessafari.html. Se puder postar o código, seria bom.

Comment: atualizei acima o código que utilizo

Comment: Lembre-se que se for usar a sessão entre os diversos frames, há uma grande chance de não funcionar direito em browser nenhum na primeira carga da página, principalmente se vc seta a sessão em um dos frames. Aí pode até funcionar bem, mas como coincidência (pois depende da ordem de carga de cada elemento a propagação inicial da sessão por cookies). Neste caso um possível caminho é criar a sessão no frameset e incluir o ID da sessão no URL do frame, por exemplo `<frame src="corpo.html?SID=...">`.

Comment: Como o @Bacco comentou, provavelmente o problema está no fato de carregar seu site em frames, o que não é recomendado hoje em dia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme já dito nos comentários, antes de mais nada é preciso que seu navegador esteja aceitando *cookies*.

Uma vez certificado isto, considere que se for usar a sessão entre os diversos frames, há uma grande chance de não funcionar direito em browser nenhum na primeira carga da página, principalmente se vc seta a sessão em um dos frames.

Pode até funcionar bem em alguma condição especial, mas como coincidência, pois a propagação da sessão entre os framens depende da ordem de carga de cada elemento. Pode muito bem acontecer de o *cookie* ser setado em um dos frames, porém a carga do outro já ter se iniciado sem receber o valor deste *cookie*, portanto o script deste já não terá acesso à sessão criada. Pior ainda: pode estar criando uma nova, que sobreescreva o *cookie* ou que seja sobreescrita.

Neste caso um possível caminho é criar a sessão no frameset e incluir o ID da sessão no URL do frame, por exemplo `<frame src="corpo.html?SID=...">`, lembrando-se de ajustar as variáveis para o seu caso concreto.

Answer (score 2):

Sessões no php usam um Session Cookie, então verifique o seguinte:

- O seu Safari está permitindo cookies? por padrão o Session Cookie é chamado "phpsessionid"
- Você tem certeza que usou o `session_start()`? (seria interessante usar também um `session_name()`)

Espero ter ajudado